# Como generar un evento al hacer click en un checkbox con javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

Tengo el siguiente código, lo que hace es sumar variables y colocar el resultado final en un input, ahora lo que quiero es que al hacer click en un checkbox, le sume 5 al resultado totaly se actualice el input con el nuevo valor, y si le vuelvo a dar click al check le reste esos 5 que le sume y se actualice de nuevo

```html
var uno = $("#input1").val();
var dos = $("#input2").val();
var tres = $("#input3").val();

var total = uno * 1.5 +  dos * 0.5 + tres * 0.5;
document.getElementById("total").value = total;



<input name="total" id="total" class="form-control"/>

<label><input id="agregar" type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
```

Comment: La pregunta está incompleta. ¿Qué quieres que ocurra cuando se le dé clic por tercera, cuarta, quinta, `n...` vez?

Comment: Que sea uno y uno, la primera vez  sume, luego reste, sume de nuevo y así

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo mediante un evento **change**, que capture cuando el **checkbox** cambia y entonces, dependiendo de si está seleccionado o deseleccionado, sumarle o restarle 5 a la variable **total**.

**JQUERY**

```
var total = 10;

$('#agregar').change(function () {
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
    total = total + 5;
  }
  else {
    total = total - 5;
  }

  alert(total);

});
```

Luego, para insertar el valor de la variable **total** dentro del **input**, lo harías mediante la función `val()`.

**JQUERY**

```
var total = 10;

$('#agregar').change(function () {
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
    total = total + 5;
  }
  else {
    total = total - 5;
  }

  $('#total').val(total);

});
```

Como puedes ver, lo único que he hecho ha sido cambiar la salida por pantalla (el **alert**) por la inserción de la variable dentro del **input text**.

Answer (score 1):

Así lo haría yo utilizando JavaScript. Hay que tener en cuenta que el valor de un input es una cadena de texto. También es posible que algún usuario deje algún input vacío o que ponga un valor que no es un número. Espero que lo encuentres útil.

```js
agregar.addEventListener("change", function(){
  var uno = esNumero(input1.value);
  var dos = esNumero(input2.value);
  var tres = esNumero(input3.value);
  console.log(uno,dos,tres)
  var suma = uno * 1.5 +  dos * 0.5 + tres * 0.5;
  total.value = suma;
})

function esNumero(n) {
  return (!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)) ? parseFloat(n) : 0;
}
```

```html
<input name="input1" id="input1"  placeholder="input1" />
<input name="input2" id="input2"  placeholder="input2" />
<input name="input3" id="input3"  placeholder="input3" />

<input name="total" id="total" class="form-control" placeholder="total" />

<label><input id="agregar" type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
```